# How to solve Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **belongsToMany** relationship between the students and departments. **Now i want to fetch all the departments of students where subject_id of departments is null**. I below code but it gives me the following error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `departments` where `subject_id` is null and exists (select * from `students` inner join `department_student` on `students`.`id` = `department_student`.`student_id` where `departments`.`id` = `department_student`.`department_id` and `id` = 16 and `students`.`deleted_at` is null))

```
$departments=Department::where('subject_id','=',null)
                        ->whereHas('students',function($student){
                            $student->where('id',Auth::id());
                        })
                        ->get();
dd($departments);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify the table name where you are referencing the `id` to avoid the ambiguity.

```
$departments=Department::where('subject_id','=',null)
->whereHas('students',function($student){ 
      $student->where('student.id',Auth::id()); //Notice the student.id instead of id
  })->get();
```

Comment: yest it solves the problem but i think the table name i will get from the relationships thats why i diddnt use that